# Cut or split chain

Tags: outdoor

Bought some chain to help make swing set accessories lower to the ground... but can't figure out what to do to make short pieces of chain from the one big long chain I got at the store. And when I do get the long chain into shorter pieces, how do I connect them to the existing chain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To cut chain, you can use a bolt cutter (size de pendant on the chain links) or, what I've used, is an angle grinder. Most hardware stores have a bolt cutter next to the chain.

To connect them together, you need a chain connector. They look like this:

http://www.centrevilletrailer.com/parts/part_detail.cfm?productid=1623

any place that sells chain will have them.

Comment: And most places that sell chain will cut the chain for you to whatever length you need.

Answer (score 2):

To make the short sections of chain you need simply cut a link at the required distance.

To join the chains you need something the same size and strength as the other links in the chain, but that can be opened and closed. I found [this page](http://www.sailnet.com/forums/gear-maintenance/10891-how-connect-two-pieces-chain.html) on a sailing community that talks about "mid links" and "repair links". If you mention these two terms at your hardware store they might know one of them.